# Increasing length of closed spline (scaling)

Tags: transformation, spline

I have a 2D closed spline and I need to increase its total length by a factor `k`, without changing its curvature, basically scaling. If this spline was a circle, I would divide the length by 4: `w = k/4` and use `w` as a scaling factor for both axes in a 2D transformation matrix.

Am I wrong in thinking I can use the same approach for a more irregular/complex spline?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the arclength of **any** curve by a factor $k$, you should use $k$ as the scaling factor for both axes in a 2D transformation matrix. Then, if the original curve's arclength was $s$, the transformed curve's arclength will be $k*s$.

I don't understand what you wrote about scaling a circle. If you scale by $w$, then arclength will be scaled by $w$.

And scaling will *always* affect curvature. The curvature of a circle of radius $r$ is $1/r$. After scaling by a factor $k$, its radius will be $kr$, so its curvature will be $1/kr$. Maybe you were using the word "curvature" in some loose (non-mathematical) sense.

Comment: Hey @bubba, yes I was meaning "curvature" as in "curve shape", basically it should look like a zoomed in/out version of the original one. So to be clear, you're saying that if the spline (let's imagine it's an oval) length is 10mm and I want to make it 11mm, I will have to use a scaling factor of 1.1 on both axes? Thanks.

Comment: Correct. Scaling by 1.1 on both axes will change arclength from 10 to 11. Maybe this is not relevant, but this caling will change area by  factor of 1.21.